# Specify empty values by character string in PROC IMPORT

Tags: csv, import, sas, missing-data

I'm coming to SAS from R in which this problem is fairly easy to solve.

I'm trying to load a bunch of CanSim CSV files (one [example table here](http://www5.statcan.gc.ca/access_acces/alternative_alternatif?l=eng&keng=1362.9&kfra=1362.9&teng=Download%20file%20from%20CANSIM&tfra=Fichier%20extrait%20de%20CANSIM&loc=http://www20.statcan.gc.ca/tables-tableaux/cansim/csv/02820135-eng.zip&dispext=CSV)) with a `%Macro` function.

```
%Macro ReadCSV (infile , outfile );
PROC IMPORT 
        DATAFILE= &infile.
        OUT= &outfile.
        DBMS=CSV REPLACE;
 GETNAMES=YES;
 DATAROW=2;
RUN;
%Mend ReadCSV;
%ReadCSV("\\DATA\CanSimTables\02820135-eng.csv", work.cs02820135);
%ReadCSV("\\DATA\CanSimTables\02820158-eng.csv", work.cs02820158);
```

The problem is that the numeric `Value` column has ".." in all the csv's whenever the value is missing.  This is creating an error when `IMPORT` gets to the rows with this character string.

Is there some way to tell `IMPORT` that any ".." should be removed or treated as missing values?  (I found forums referring to the `DSD` option, but that doesn't seem to help me here.)

Thanks!

Comment: Do the files have the same layout every year?  If so you should just write a data step to read the files. Then you will have control over how it reads the data.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly, but no(?): In each CSV file the rows are indexed by location and time, which can differ between files.  The columns (the number and their names) differ.  However, there are similarities. For example, the numeric value is always in a column called "Value". Does that help me?

Comment: Can you please paste the SAS log? The SAS log displays information about the import and the data step used - we can use it as template to modify behaviour.

Comment: You could process the file as text and convert the `..` to `.` so that SAS will know you mean a missing value, but it is probably just easier to write a data step to read it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PROC IMPORT can only guess at the structure of your data. For example it might see the `..` and assume the column contains a character string instead of a number.  It can also make other decisions that can made the generated dataset useless.

You will be better served to write you own data step code to read the file.  It is not very difficult to do.  For your example linked file all I did was copy and paste the first row of the CSV file and remove the commas, make the names valid variable names and take some guesses as to how long to make the character variables.

```
data want ;
  infile "&path/&fname" dsd truncover firstobs=2 ;
  length Ref_Date $7 GEO $100 Geographical_classification $20
         CHARACTERISTICS $100 STATISTICS DATATYPE $50 Vector Coordinate $20
         Value 8
  ;
  input (Ref_Date -- Value) (??) ;
run;
```

The `??` modifier will tell SAS not to report any errors when trying the convert the text in the VALUE column into a number.  So the `..` and other garbage in the file will generate missing values.

Comment: Excellent. The `??` modifier seems to be what I needed.  Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not explicitly relevant for this question, but - if your issue were "N" or "D" or similar that you wanted to become missing, there would be a somewhat easier solution: the `missing statement` (importantly distinct from the `missing option`).

```
missing M;
```

That tells SAS to see a single character `M` in the data as a missing value, and read it in accordingly. It would read it in as `.M` special missing value, which is functionally similar to `.` regular missing (but not actually equal in an equality statement).